# In neovim, how do I get a file to open at the same line number I closed it at last time?

Tags: neovim

```
au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
```

This code is valid in vim. It is the syntax of vimscript. It can also work in neovim's configuration file init.vim. how can I achieve the same effect in init.lua?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this should do it

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"BufReadPost"}, {
    pattern = {"*"},
    callback = function()
        if vim.fn.line("'\"") > 1 and vim.fn.line("'\"") <= vim.fn.line("$") then
            vim.fn.nvim_exec("normal! g'\"",false)
        end
    end
})
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: Recently getting an error with this one, had to change `vim.fn.nvim_exec` to `vim.api.nvim_exec`